# Access is denied error on XDomainRequest

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, cross-domain, xdomainrequest

I'm trying to use microsoft XDomainRequest to send cross domain request.
Here is the code

> ```
> ...
> if ($.browser.msie && window.XDomainRequest) {
>   // Use Microsoft XDR
>   var xdr = new XDomainRequest();
>     xdr.open("POST", "http://graph.facebook.com/1524623057/");
>
>   xdr.send();
> } 
>  ....
> ```

It gives `SCRIPT5: Access is denied.` error on  `xdr.open(...)` line.

Comment: 9, I have changed to 8 with developer tools, but the same result

Comment: What is the content-type header you're sending?

Comment: Yes, see point 4: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx

Comment: How I can set header to XDomainRequest object ?

Comment: I think i got the problem (point 7).

Comment: @jeffamaphone Do I understand the item #4 correctly? Only plain text? What if I want to get JSON formatted data or a XML structure? In practice, those CAN be transmitted as text, although technically speaking it's not "text" but "application/json" and "application/xml"...

Answer (score 59, accepted):

I found the reason of this problem. As stated in [Point 7](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/ieinternals/archive/2010/05/13/xdomainrequest-restrictions-limitations-and-workarounds.aspx):

> **Requests must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page**
>
> This restriction means that if your AJAX page is at `http://example.com`, then your target URL must also begin with ***HTTP***. Similarly, if your AJAX page is at `https://example.com`, then your target URL must also begin with ***HTTPS***.

Comment: Point 7 being "Requests must be targeted to the same scheme as the hosting page". I was struggling with this same problem too, calling an **https** address from an **http** page. Thanks for the link!

Comment: I understood that, but is there any way to fix this problem and can access https: ajax from http sites.

Comment: this really help me a lot! I spend hours trying to figure out :)

Answer (score -1):

See this:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc288060(v=vs.85).aspx

It describes how the server must respond with a certain header, Access-Control-Allow-Origin.

Comment: Hm.  So I see now that this URL does return that header with a value of "*".  So that's not it.