# IE9 giving "access is denied" error when using XDomainRequest

Tags: javascript, ajax

I need to make a GET request to a remote Domain Name (also controlled by me) but can't use jQuery. I am using old fashioned JS. I am aware that XDomainRequest should be used for IE8/9 but despite the code catering for this I am still getting an "Access is denied" error. Works fine on newer versions of IE and other browsers.

```
if (window.XDomainRequest) xhr = new XDomainRequest();
else if (window.XMLHttpRequest) xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
else xhr = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

xhr.open("GET", "https://www.remote-domain-name.com/index.php?"+params, true);
```

Do I need to change the JS for my request or perhaps I need to change the header that is returned by remote-domain-name.com/index.php. This is currently set to:

```
header('Access-Control-Allow-Origin: *');
```

Comment: Are you going from http to https?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8464262/access-is-denied-error-on-xdomainrequest

Comment: I am! http to https. I have changed so the location.protocol is set dynamically and this has solved the issue. Thank you @epascarello